# A Convolution Integral Equation

Tags: integral-transforms, functional-equations

Is there any close-form solution for a function $f(t)$ satisfied the below equation:
$f(t)=g(t)+\frac{1}{t^2}(h(t)*f(t))$. Operator $*$ is convolution integral, and $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ are known functions.

Comment: Please provide more detail, for example what class of functions are you considering? Measurable? Smooth? C^1? Schwarz? etc

Comment: On that set $f$ is defined?

Comment: $t>0$ and is a real value. At the first, we have no condition on $f$.

Comment: And what is a "closed form"? A formula with Fourier transforms and convolutions is a "closed form" or not?

Comment: yes, that's ok. The closed form means a straight expression between the desired function or its transform versus the other known functions and variables.

Comment: I think you should give explicitly $g$ and $h$. For $t\ne 0$, a Fourier transform of this equation gives $f''(\omega)+h(\omega)f(\omega)=g''(\omega)$ that has known solutions just for some special cases of h.